# error: no match for 'operator[]

Tags: c++

Ошибка возникла на первом `cout`,
полный текст ошибки:

> error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::vectorstd::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int> >' and 'std::pairstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int>')|

```
int ss = 0;
string st1, k = "";
cin >> st1;
vector <pair<string, int>> h(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < st1.size(); i++)
{
    if (st1[i] == '*')
    {
        h[ss].first = k;
        h[ss].second = (st1.find(k));
        k = "";
        ss++;
        continue;
    }
    k += st1[i];
}

for (auto i: h)
{
    cout << h[i].first() << "\n";
    cout << h[i].second() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Уверен, что Вы заметили что этот цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < st1.size(); i++)
```

отличается от этого

```
for (auto i: h)
```

Циклы, подобные второму, появились в С++11. Такой цикл называется "цикл основанный на диапазоне". Что он делает? Он по очереди инициализирует переменную `i` всеми значениями из контейнера `h`. В Вашем векторе хранятся элементы типа `pair<string,int>`. Значит и `i` имеет этот тип, поэтому выводить нужно так:

```
for (auto i: h)
{
    cout << i.first << "\n";
    cout << i.second << "\n";
}
```